# Is there a standard way to "find in page" in jQuery (ideally without a plugin)

Tags: jquery

I'd like to offer a search field on a page which would mimic the "find in page" functionality of the browser.  Assuming we can't invoke the browser's own feature (window.find() seems non-standard), I'd like code that searches, highlights matches, offers next/prev match, etc.

I could not find usable code to do that, nor a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Why not use the browser search

Comment: to be accessible to low-computer-literacy users, who may not be aware of the browser's find feature. The site deals with literary texts, and the search feature is particularly useful, so I want to make sure it is maximally discoverable.

Comment: Why not just put a large "press ctrl+f to search" or maybe even a large magnifying glass next to a picture of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. Not trying to troll, but I've just found in general it's not a good idea to re-implement a built in browser feature; the browser al.ost always does it better.

Comment: Because it would be far less elegant, visually.  I agree with you and am not looking to re-implement the browser's functionality -- indeed, if there were a way to trigger it with a *clickable button* rather than a key combination, that would be enough for me.  Apparently, window.find() used to do that, but it is nonstandard, and apparently no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `:contains` and `:visible` selectors.
Something like:

```
function findInPage(q) {
  var $target = $(':visible:contains("'+q+'")')
  while( $target.length ) {
    $target = $target.children(':contains("'+q+'")');
  }
  return $target.end();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

[Domo](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/vpav6tL1/)

Comment: Thank you!  That'd be very helpful, if I'll end having to implement it myself.  I'm looking for ready code already doing the highlighting, the skipping between matches, etc.

Comment: Updated the answer with Mark.js plugin that might have what you need.

Comment: Oh, perfect, thank you!  This demo is exactly what I need: 
https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/